# How to get Django form field from model field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'd like to create a form that includes fields from two separate models, along with some other regular (non-model) fields. The form will create an instance of each model. I don't *think* I can use inline formsets for this, since I don't want to include all the fields from both models.

I'd like to create the form field without hard-coding the type of the model fields.

I know I can get a form field from a model field using `model_field.formfield()`. But how can I get the specific model field?

My first solution:

```
def get_fields(model_class):
    fields = {}
    for f in model_class._meta.fields:
        fields[f.name] = f

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    foo_name = get_fields(Foo)['name'].formfield()
    bar_name = get_fields(Bar)['name'].formfield()
    other_field = ...
```

Is there an equivalent of `get_fields` already? Is this a bad idea? I'm uncomfortable relying on the model `_meta` attribute. Or am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Comment: Your solution sounds reasonable to me, altho, I don't see why you dont want to hard code those 2 fields; perhaps you get the models dynamically.

Comment: I want to avoid hard-coding the type of the form field in case I ever change the type of the corresponding model field. Not sure what you meant about getting the models dynamically... ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You also can take a look at `django.forms.models.fields_for_model`.
That should give you a dictionary of fields, and then you can add the fields of the form

Comment: Hadn't noticed that method, thanks. That's the answer I was looking for, but perhaps Casey Stark's suggestion is more appropriate.

Answer (score 13):

You should never have to build the fields yourself unless you want some special behavior.

This should be as simple as using two `ModelForm`s and an extra `Form` inside one `<form>` tag in your template with one submit button.

in forms.py:

```
class Model1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = ('fields', 'you', 'want')

class Model2Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = ('fields', 'you', 'want')

class ExtraFieldsForm(forms.Form):
    extra_field = form.TextField() # or whatever field you're looking for
```

in views.py:

```
form1 = Model1Form(request.POST or None)
form2 = Model2Form(request.POST or None)
form3 = ExtraFieldsForm(request.POST or None)

if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid() and form3.is_valid():
    form1.save()
    form2.save()
    form3.save()

    ...do other stuff like a redirect...
```

and in the template:

```
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        {{ form1|as_uni_form }}
        {{ form2|as_uni_form }}
        {{ form3|as_uni_form }}
        <div class="form_block">
            <input type="submit" value="Save both models"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I'm used to using django-uni-form, but you can render the form fields however you like. Good luck with your site.

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me do use multiple `Form` objects within a single `<form>` element. Thanks for the suggestion - I'll try that out tonight.

Comment: Cool. I hope it works for you. I've seen it done before but this isn't tested. You might need to play with the view logic to get what you want.

Answer (score 12):

There is now a [documented API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_field) for getting the model field from a model class:

```
my_model_field = MyModel._meta.get_field('my_model_field_name')
```

Although it's not officially documented until Django 1.8, this should work with earlier Django versions too.

Once you have this, you can get the form field like so:

```
form_field = my_model_field.formfield()
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution can be to create one 'uber'-form that aggregates the concrete modelforms. The  form supports the methods that a form normally provides and it forward them to all the child forms. Some will be simple, other complicated. The big advantage of that approach is that no code beyond the form is affected (client validation code and alike). The concept isn't really revolutionary but i guess complicated to add afterwards.
Paul

Answer (score 0):

It's still undocumented as far as I know, but [since Django 3.0](https://github.com/django/django/pull/11589) you can make a form field from a single model field called `field_name` with:

```
MyModel.field_name.field.formfield()
```

If your model is a [**`parler.models.TranslatableModel`**](https://django-parler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/parler.models.html#the-translatablemodel-model), and the `field_name` is inside `translations`, you can use:

```
MyModel.translations.field.model.field_name.field.formfield()
```

---

Or, if you prefer a bit more verbose, but better documented ways, you can use:

```
MyModel._meta.get_field("field_name").formfield()
```

and

```
MyModel._parler_meta.get_model_by_related_name("translations")._meta.get_field("field_name").formfield()
```

See:
[**Django `get_field`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_field)
[**django-parler `get_model_by_related_name`**](https://github.com/django-parler/django-parler/blob/00df9926763e620823a33eaaeefbf1266dc9bf8f/parler/models.py#L190-L191)